# how to correctly install apache2, php5, mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: installation, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

What is the most correct method of installing apache 2 server, php5, mysql and phpMyAdmin?

I installed it this week, and I had a lot problems without solutions, so now that I reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 I don't want to make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a command line:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Another option is `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`?

Comment: I installed `lamp-server^`. Does it include phpMyAdmin? How can I access it from browser?

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` and comment the line that says `php_admin_flag engine Off`  "DO NOT MAKE IT ON JUST COMMENT IT OUT"

Comment: @Sithu, cross-reference [this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785440), and specifically [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785440/how-to-install-lamp-server-on-ubuntu#comment1178103_785443) about the caret ('`^`'). I quote, "`tasksel` is no longer needed. `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` will activate the "task" (mind the carret[sic]: that is used to tell `apt-get` to install the task).  – Rinzwind | Jun 10, 2016 at 20:40".The comment refers to not needing <strike>`sudo apt-get install tasksel`>`sudo tasksel`>...</strike>, but rather, `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Answer (score 11):

Install Apache2

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install php mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php-mbstring php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5


sudo mysql_install_db
```

Set password for mysql

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Then install the php

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

Then to check the PHP

```
sudo vim /var/www/info.php

<?php
phpinfo();
?>


sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Install phpmyadmin

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

While installation it will ask for some settings for choosing apache server or lighthttpd choosem apache

Choose Apache

Choose no for dbconfig-common

Now Navigate to the Web Browser and openup the IP mentioned with /phpmyadmin/

```
eg : http://192.168.122.69/phpmyadmin/
```

Use Your Login what u used for mysql installation

Login Information I always use for demo purpose is

root and password is admin123

Comment: `vas@LenovoZ580:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install php mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php-mbstring php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring`

Comment: Remove the php-mbstring and install using other

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and my favorite is - open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

Comment: @user118136 I just added mine for future readers - did see the solved mark.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed some steps to install php 5.3 + Apache on Ubuntu 14.

First, write the following repositories to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-old.list`

```
deb http://55.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
```

run `apt-get update` and then

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 php5-cli=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 php5-common=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 libapache2-mod-php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 apache2=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9  apache2-mpm-prefork=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9 apache2.2-common=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9 apache2.2-bin=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.9 php5-pgsql=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19 php5-xdebug=2.1.0-1
```

I've tested each command, it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

1. ALWAYS

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Basic:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apache2 php5-common mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
   ```
3. Extras:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-gd
   ```
4. Make sure you ALWAYS run mysql_secure_installation after you have installed MySQL

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.10 I had an error installing `phpmyadmin`:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
```

When I loaded the page in my browser it came up as:

```
error: json missing
```

Found the answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/639945/how-to-fix-the-phpmyadmin-error-json-extension-is-missing.